# Error using virtualenv to change python version for existing virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a windows 7 OS with python 3.5.

I have to upgrade the python version to 3.6.

I have downloaded and installed the python package.

Previously, I have run the following command using powershell to change the python version in the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv env3 -p C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

However, I receive the following error when I attempt to run the above command:

```
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv env3 -p
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\py ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandN
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have run powershell as an adminstrator, but the error persists.

I have searched SO & Google but cannot find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `PATH` variable. You may have the old path of virtualenv.

Alternatively, creation of virtual environments is done by executing the command venv:

```
c:\>c:\Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
```

See the doc [Creating virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)